# How to write syntax for differential item functioning (DIF) in WinBUGS?

Tags: winbugs14, winbugs

How to add data in syntax of WinBUGS 14 for [differential item function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_item_functioning) (DIF)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to search for "differential item functioning bayesian" to find some resources. From what I found it is clear that the model would look something like:

```
y[i,j,k] ~ Bernoulli(p[i,j,k])
logit(p[i,j,k]) <- ....
```

I.e. logistic regression. See resources:

- [A non-parametric Bayesian diagnostic for detecting
  differential item functioning in IRT models](http://www.glicko.net/research/dif.pdf)
- [A Bayesian Approach for Fitting a Random Effect Differential
  Item Functioning Across Group Units](http://www.news.mot.go.th/mot/exec/TSA/Journal_onweb%5Cvol4%5Cabstractv4_3.pdf)
- [Modeling Differential Item Functioning (DIF) Using Multilevel Logistic Regression Models: A Bayesian Perspective](http://digitool.fcla.edu/R/QVB5D1X4LIKYNY7CEFRYTJ7MAFTJT1A56E2VH6D3IQQQI6EDPY-00001?func=dbin-jump-full&object_id=121786&local_base=GEN01&pds_handle=GUEST)

For more resources type "differential item functioning bayesian" into google.